# Text classification. TFIDF and Naive Bayes?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, nlp

I'm attempting a text classification task, where I have training data of around 500 restaurant reviews that are labelled across 12 categories. I spent longer than I should have implementing TF.IDF and cosine similarity for the classification of test data, only to get some very poor results (0.4 F-measure). With time not on my side now, I need to implement something significantly more effective that doesn't have a steep learning curve. I am considering using the TF.IDF values in conjunction with Naive Bayes. Does this sound sensible? I know if I can get my data in the right format, I can do this with Scikit learn. Is there anything else you recommend I consider?

Thank you.

Comment: With vectors of TF.IDF values for each category, using the training data, how would I go about training a classifier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try to use fasttext: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/fasttext . It can be used to classify text like this:

(don't forget to download a pretrained model here https://s3-us-west-1.amazonaws.com/fasttext-vectors/wiki.en.zip by changing the language if it's not english)

```
import fasttext

model = fasttext.load_model('wiki.en.bin')  # the name of the pretrained model

classifier = fasttext.supervised('train.txt', 'model', label_prefix='__label__')

result = classifier.test('test.txt')
print ('P@1:', result.precision)
print ('R@1:', result.recall)
print ('Number of examples:', result.nexamples)
```

Every line in your training and test sets should be like this:

> __label__classname Your restaurant review blah blah blah

Comment: Thanks @Vinzee - I'll give this a shot. Is there a smaller model I can use? University computers don't have enough capacity...

Comment: `result.precision` and `result.recall` are returning NaN and `result.nexamples` returns 0. Looking on the Facebook group for FastText, this appears to be a common error. Any idea why it's happening?